# ToPaginatedListAsync<T>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm using this method and I would likely have a code review. Also, I have one concern and is that `source.Count()` is executing synchronously and I don't know how to make it async in this context.

```
public static class IQueryableExtensions
    {
        public static Task<PaginatedList<T>> ToPaginatedListAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, int pageSize, int pageIndex = 1)
        {
            var count = source.Count();
            return
                source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
                .AsAsyncEnumerable()
                .Aggregate(new PaginatedList<T>(
                    totalCount: count,
                    pageSize : pageSize, 
                    pageIndex: pageIndex), (list, x) => { list.Add(x); return list; });
        }

    }

    public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
    {
        private int pageIndex;
        private int pageSize;
        public PaginatedList(IEnumerable<T> collection, int totalCount, int pageSize, int pageIndex) : base(collection)
        {
            TotalCount = totalCount;
            PageSize = pageSize;
            PageIndex = pageIndex;
        }

        public PaginatedList(int totalCount, int pageSize, int pageIndex) : base()
        {
            TotalCount = totalCount;
            PageSize = pageSize;
            PageIndex = pageIndex;
        }

        public PaginatedList(int capacity, int totalCount, int pageSize, int pageIndex) : base(capacity)
        {
            TotalCount = totalCount;
            PageSize = pageSize;
            PageIndex = pageIndex;
        }

        public int PageIndex
        {
            get { return pageIndex; }
            private set
            {
                if (value <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(PageIndex));
                pageIndex = value;
            }
        }

        public int PageSize
        {
            get { return pageSize; }
            private set
            {
                if (value <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(PageSize));
                pageSize = value;
            }
        }

        public int TotalPages => (int)Math.Ceiling(TotalCount / (double)PageSize);

        public bool HasPreviousPage => PageIndex > 1;

        public bool HasNextPage => PageIndex < TotalPages;

        public int TotalCount { get; }
    }
```

This code and updates are available at: https://gist.github.com/Bartmax/5a55ff88413174d49301

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> public static Task<PaginatedList<T>> ToPaginatedListAsync<T>(
>   this IQueryable<T> source, int pageSize, int pageIndex = 1)
> ```

Your method *says* `Async`, returns a `Task<PaginatedList<T>>`, but... it doesn't say `async`.

```
public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> ToPaginatedListAsync<T>(
  this IQueryable<T> source, int pageSize, int pageIndex = 1)
```

With the `async` keyword specified, you can now `await` your result - not sure what `AsAsyncEnumerable` does, but it doesn't seem necessary then:

```
return await Task.Run(() =>
{
    var count = source.Count();
    return
        source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
        .Aggregate(new PaginatedList<T>(
            totalCount: count,
            pageSize: pageSize,
            pageIndex: pageIndex), (list, x) => { list.Add(x); return list; });
});
```

---

On the other hand, you're not really *aggregating* with `Aggregate`; LINQ stands for *Language-INtegrated **Query***, and a query that has side effects isn't really a query.

> ```
> source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
> ```

That part is fine. Or is it? Why do you need to `-1`? Is `pageIndex` 1-based? That's pretty confusing, given the list itself is 0-based. What's the meaning of "page 0" then? Why make it throw when assigned to 0, *in the setter*, when the only caller for that setter is in the constructor? Better fail early and put a guard clause in the constructor and throw that `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` with a shorter stack trace.

I don't know why, the more I look at the `Aggregate` call, the more I want the method to be returning an `IEnumerable<T>`.

The caller already knows the `totalCount` (well it *can* have it), the `pageIndex` and the `pageSize`, and you're only ever returning a single page - I don't see why a `PaginatedList<T>` needs to know this metadata at that point.

If you can return an `IEnumerable<T>`, then you could `yield` the results and have this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OfPage<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize = 10)
{
    foreach (var item in source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize))
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Notice I made the `pageIndex` mandatory, and `pageSize` optional - anyone using this API would expect to be able to pass a page index as a first argument to a method called `OfPage`.

Now, `yield` is pretty much the opposite of `async`, and it's not really buying anything here, since `Take` should already materialize the query, so you could have this `async` one-liner then:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> OfPageAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize = 10)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => source.Skip((pageIndex - 1)*pageSize).Take(pageSize));
}
```

If `PaginatedList<T>` doesn't need to know the `totalCount`, `pageIndex` and `pageSize`, then it doesn't need to exist - it's not adding any functionality, merely carrying metadata that the caller already knows, and if it needs to be carried along with the items on that page, then `PaginatedList<T>` can exist, but then as a *composition*:

```
public class PageItems<T> // not a list
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> _items;
    private readonly int _page;
    private readonly int _pageSize;

    public PageItems(IEnumerable<T> items, int page, int pageSize)
    {
        _items = items;
        _page = page;
        _pageSize = pageSize;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get { return _items; } }
    public int PageIndex { get { return _pageIndex; } }
    public int PageSize { get { return _pageSize; } }
}
```

Notice that's exposing `IEnumerable<T>` and not `List<T>` or even `IList<T>`: if you don't need to do anything other than *iterate* these items, you don't need a `List`, you need an `IEnumerable`. The code doesn't change much:

```
public static async Task<PageItems<T>> OfPageAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize = 10)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        var items = source.Skip((pageIndex - 1)*pageSize).Take(pageSize)
        return new PageItems(items, pageIndex, pageSize);
    });
}
```

Comment: Very good points indeed!! I used the throw in the setter to avoid having all those on 3 constructors. removing the list will fix that. I'm not aware if `Task.Run` instead of using `await` with `CountAsync` and `ToListAsync` have any side effects? Are you sure `Take` does materialize the query? I wonder why there is no `TakeAsync` method.

Comment: Why do you recommend composition instead of implementing `IEnumerable` interface? I like consumers to be able to `foreach`

Comment: It doesn't prevent `foreach` over the exposed `IEnumerable<Item>`, and composition doesn't prevent implementing `IEnumerable` and an indexed getter and whatnot... I don't see any problem with composition.

Comment: Thank you Mat, I included a link for code and revisions in the question. Let me know if it looks good! Updates were made based on the great feedback from all answers/comments.

Comment: @BartCalixto " I'm not aware if Task.Run instead of using await with CountAsync and ToListAsync have any side effects?" -- I'd recommend Stephen Cleary's blog post [Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).

Comment: @mjolka that's a very nice article, thanks! (gosh I've been doing it wrong!)

Answer (score 4):

> I have one concern and is that `source.Count()` is executing synchronously and I don't know how to make it async

Use `CountAsync` instead:

```
public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> ToPaginatedListAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, int pageSize, int pageIndex = 1)
{
    var count = await source.CountAsync();
    return await source.Skip() ...
}
```

Note that it's [recommended to use `ConfigureAwait(false)`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) in "library" methods such as this one.

Comment: this clearly fixes my concern. and the `ConfigureAwait(false)` is a great addition. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit odd:

```
return
    source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
    .AsAsyncEnumerable()
    .Aggregate(new PaginatedList<T>(
        totalCount: count,
        pageSize : pageSize, 
        pageIndex: pageIndex), (list, x) => { list.Add(x); return list; });
    }
```

It seems like all you really want is:

```
var pagedList = new PaginatedList<T>(count, pageSize, pageIndex);
var pageItems = source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
pagedList.AddRange(pageItems);
return pagedList;
```

I've removed your labels for the constructor parameters as I think it's fairly obvious without them. Cleaning it all up and including advice from other answers:

```
public static class IQueryableExtensions
{
    public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> ToPaginatedListAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, int pageSize, int pageIndex = 1)
    {
        if (source == null) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        }

        var totalCount = await source.CountAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        var pagedList = new PaginatedList<T>(totalCount, pageSize, pageIndex);
        var pageItems = source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        pagedList.AddRange(pageItems);
        return pagedList;
    }
}
```

You could make getting the items async too by doing:

```
 var pageItems = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
 pagedList.AddRange(pageItems);
```

Comment: i used the labels because there's another constructor that accepts same type arguments (int,int,int) and may be prone to errors if changed. I'm wondering if do I really want/need a list and all those ctros...